# TCP window size in Linux with kernel 2.4 or 2.6

Tags: tcp, operating-system, window, fingerprinting

Can anybody tell me why according to this site - [Passive OS identification](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-11&post=Passive-OS-Fingerprinting),
TCP window size in Linux with kernels 2.4 or 2.6 is 5840? I mean, is there any official documentation where i can read about it?

Thank you!